Problema con consulta con JOIN en SQL (PHP)
Soy nuevo en PHP/MySQL y estoy usando en mi proyecto una base de datos con dos columnas: pedidos y usuarios. Mi objetivo ahora es renderizar en mi archivo ver_pedidos.php todos los pedidos de un determinado usuario guardados en la base de datos. Lo primero que hice fue crear un campo llamado usuario_id en mi tabla de pedidos con una clave foránea que se conecte con el id de un usuario. Con esto ahora puedo hacer una consulta SELECT y buscar los registros de pedidos cuyo usuario_id sea igual al id de mi usuario actual. El problema que estoy teniendo actualmente es que la respuesta de la base solo me trae el primer registro de los tres que tengo con el mismo id y además me lo trae de esta forma:
array(8) { ["pedido_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["usuario_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["cliente"]=> string(5) "Mauro" ["apellido"]=> string(5) "Mario" ["cod_postal"]=> string(4) "1890" ["direccion"]=> string(8) "Pepe 120" ["pedido"]=> string(10) "1421411414" ["img_pedido"]=> string(16) "../img/Chubb.jpg" }

Tengo tres elementos en la base de datos con el mismo usuario_id pero solamente me devuelve el primero y no sé por qué. Además el array tiene 8 elementos, ¿no debería ser uno solo, un objeto con los 8 campos adentro?
Paso el resto de mi archivo ver_pedidos.php para brindar todo el contexto:
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
        header('Location:http://localhost/panaderia/session/iniciar_sesion.php');
        exit;
    }

    $sesion_actual = $_SESSION["admin"];

    include("parts/head.php");
    include("parts/header.php");
?>
<div class="realizar_bg">
    <div class="pedidos_">
        <h1>Pedidos</h1>
        <?php 
            include("db/conexion.php"); #mysqli_connect()

            $query_usuario = mysqli_query($base, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '$sesion_actual' OR email = '$sesion_actual'");
            if(!$query_usuario){
                header('Location:http://localhost/panaderia/ver_pedidos.php?user_error');
                exit;
            }else{
                $usuario_obtenido = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_usuario);
                $usuario_id = $usuario_obtenido["id"];
            }

            $query = mysqli_query($base, "SELECT pedido_id, usuario_id, cliente, apellido, cod_postal, direccion, pedido, img_pedido FROM pedidos JOIN usuarios ON pedidos.usuario_id = usuarios.id WHERE pedidos.usuario_id = $usuario_id");
            $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        ?>    

        <div style="background-color:burlywood;">
            <?php if(!$resultado){ ?>
                <p class="state_error_p">Todavía no has hecho ningún pedido.</p>    
            <?php } else {
                try{
                    echo var_dump($resultado);
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    echo $e;
                }
            } ?>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>

Saludos.

mysql_fetch_assoc() solo retorna un registro, si quieres todos usa mysql_fetch_all()

Uh era eso! Ahora me aparece un array con 3 elementos y todos los registros devueltos. Gracias!

@alan, debieras escribir eso en una respuesta.
